# Fixed points in the Von Neumann universe

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I've been thinking about proper classes and the universe recently.

Let $V_\gamma$ denote the Von Neumann hierarchy, and let $\textrm{Ord}$ denote te class of ordinals. Then, define $V(\gamma) = \textrm{otyp}(V_\gamma \; \cap \; \textrm{Ord})$. Since $V(\gamma)$ should be continuous and strictly increasing, could we apply Veblen's theorem and find (non-trivial) fixed points i.e. solutions to $V(\kappa) = \kappa$, for cardinals $\kappa$? If so, what would these fixed points look like? Note I am working with cardinals rather than ordinals as ordinal solutions, assuming they exist, would likely be far more abundant than cardinal solutions.

Also, if we define $W(\kappa) = \sup(V_\gamma \; \cap \; \textrm{Ord})$ (supremum rather than order type), than could we find a solution to $W(\kappa) < \kappa$?

Comment: $V(\gamma) = \gamma$ always!

Comment: The only $\kappa$ where $W(\kappa)<\kappa$ are when $\kappa$ is a successor ordinal: $V_\gamma\cap\mathrm{Ord}=\gamma$ for all $\gamma$, and $\sup\gamma<\gamma$ means $\gamma$ isn't $0$ nor a limit.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh, I didn't realise that when I wrote this post. But now it actually makes sense, since I'm finding the intersection with $\textrm{Ord}$.

Comment: @JunderscoreH Thanks. But I thought this would also hold for inaccessible cardinals?

Comment: @Binary198 Inaccessible cardinals are limit ordinals, so $W(\kappa)=\sup(V_\kappa\cap\mathrm{Ord})=\sup\kappa=\kappa$.  Equality will hold for all (infinite) cardinals since (infinite) cardinals are always limit ordinals.

Comment: Ah, great! Thanks. This question is somewhat different to what I actually had in mind, so I will try and post a new version.